# Change in Work-Energy Theorem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, potential-energy

We have Work-Energy Theorem as follows:
$$W_c +W_{nc} + W_{ext} = ΔK$$ $-(1)$

, where $W_c$ = work done by conservative forces,
$W_{nc}$ = work done by non-conservative forces, $W_{ext}$ = work done by external forces

Now what my teacher did is that he replaced $W_c$ with $-ΔU$, i.e.,
$$-ΔU +W_{nc} + W_{ext} = ΔK$$ $-(2)$

But isn't he changing the *system* when he is writing equation 2 from 1?

For example, if we apply force $F$ to raise an object of mass $m$ to a height $h$,
$W_F + W_{gravity} = ΔK$

 here, we are considering the object as a system to which force of gravity is external.
But if we write,

$W_F + (-ΔU)= ΔK $

 now, the potential energy is defined for a system, here the system is earth + object.
So I think our system (things we have taken in our system) has changed.

Side Question: Can't $W_{ext}$ be classified as either of $W_c$ or $W_{nc}$? Is it different from these two?